# The position of "strong enough" in "there is no headache strong enough"

Tags: word-order

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [There is no headache strong enough, that a good coffee won't relieve](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51652/there-is-no-headache-strong-enough-that-a-good-coffee-wont-relieve)

> There is no headache strong enough, that a good coffee won't relieve.

I know that this sentence is grammatically correct, but I still can't find a suitable grammar rule that would explain why *strong enough* is used after the noun in this sentence.

Why don't we say "There's no strong enough headache, that a good coffee won't relieve"?

It doesn't look like a reduced relative clause that usually occur with past participles, such as "the people skilled in design" ("the people which are skilled in design"). We usually place such adjectives like *possible*, *available*, and few others after the noun. This is not the case.

Can anybody explain the word order to me? It would be even better if someone provides a proof from a grammar book.

Comment: "[There ain't no mountain high enough //
Ain't no valley low enough //
Ain't no river wide enough //
To keep me from getting to you](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ain%27t_No_Mountain_High_Enough)."

Comment: I love googling on partial phrases. Try searching on the phrase ["there is no * enough"](http://www.google.com/search?q="there+is+no+*+enough") and scroll through the list. You will come across wonderful variants like, *there is no flag large enough*, *there is no grave deep enough*, and *there is no threatening star close enough* amongst many others.

Comment: I think *strong enough that a good coffee won't relieve* is all one adjective phrase modifying *headache*. And we tend to put long, complex adjective phrases like this after the noun - *There is no strong-enough-that-a-good-coffee-won't-relieve headache* is almost uninterpretable.

Comment: Although I have to say the original sentence sounds a bit odd to me as well. I'd be much more likely to say *There is no headache strong enough that a good coffee won't relieve it*.

Comment: So is there any rule saying that we'd better put long adjective phrases like this after the noun? I have tried to find some explanation in "Practical English Usage" by M.Swan, but I didn't find any.

Comment: This, and [the original question here on ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51652/there-is-no-headache-strong-enough-that-a-good-coffee-wont-relieve) account for most of the handful of references to OP's sentence in Google. That original question dealt with the word order, comma placement, etc. So I'm voting to close as a duplicate.

Comment: Wait to close it.. My question is rather different. And no-one has answered my question yet

Comment: The specific question requests a special codicil that applies to the noun _headache_, and the adjective _strong_, in a reduced relative clause modifying _headache_, as a predicate adjective, quantified with _enough_ binding a _that_ complement, under universal negation. Do you really want all the rules that apply to that, specifically? If you do, how much time do you have to learn them? There are a lot of them; that sentence is **very** complex.

Comment: I've just found the rule I need in "A comprehensive grammar of the English Language" by Randolph Quirk... Now it makes sense! Thanks for the answer

Comment: @Desert: Well you'll be okay then. If anyone else wants to have that font of all wisdom, they'd better hurry. Right now, Amazon have only one copy left at £90.28 -  when that's gone it might only be available at the full price of £195.60

Answer (score 5):

*Strong enough* means *so strong that S*, where *S* represents some clause relating to the strength. This is one example of a broader pattern, where both infinitive and *that* complement Ss can occur:

> ***X*** *be* (***Adj*** *enough*)/(*so* ***Adj***) *that/to* ***S***.

This is an Equative construction (the strength of *X* is such that *S* is true), but it works by specifying a minimum value of S, so it can be used with a high minimum to signify excessive degrees, and therefore is often used to boast:

- *He's tough enough to chew iron and spit nails.* (a conjoined infinitive S here)
- *Their beards are so durn tough, it seems, the hair just grows in lumps.*

  > from "Why Oh Why Did I Ever Leave Wyoming?" by the Vic Jergens band, ca 1948
  >   (the next line  is *That's why they shave with broken glass and dynamite the stumps.*)

The position of *strong enough* in this particular sentence is after *headache*, which is the antecedent of the relative clause ***which is*** strong enough.... The *which is* part gets zapped by the usual [*Whiz*-deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50962/what-is-a-noun-modifying-clause/50971#50971), leaving only the predicate adjective phrase and its complement. So it's really a clause reduced to a modifying phrase, and that's why it sits after its antecedent.

It can also occasionally occur **before** the antecedent, especially if it's quantified with  *enough* -- but **not** if it's quantified with with *so* or *too*.

- *He has a strong enough headache to kill anybody else.*
- *He has a headache strong enough to kill anybody else.*
- *He has a headache so strong that it would kill anybody else.*
- **He has a so strong headache that it would kill anybody else.*

This phenomenon is also involved in the strangeness of the video title *[Maru and the too small box](http://icanhascheezburger.com/2010/10/08/funny-pictures-video-maru-small-box/)*.

Comment: I'll go with this answer, which is (almost) infinitely cheaper than Quirk et al, and seems perfectly adequate to me.