# Does this sentence require the pronoun 'they'?

Tags: word-choice, pronouns, sentence-patterns

I have the following sentence:

> There were several dominoes—some so precariously placed that I'd
>   swear should have toppled over.

I believe it's correct, but when read quickly or out loud, it sounds kind of funny, almost like a "they" is missing.

> There were several dominoes—some so precariously placed that I'd
>   swear **they** should have toppled over.

My reason for thinking that the first sentence is the correct one is that if I strip the sentence to its essentials, the "they" definitely doesn't fit.

> There were dominoes that I'd swear should have toppled.

Am I right in thinking that "they" is not required, or is there something incorrect happening here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have apparently analyzed the *that*-clause as a Relative Clause (which wouldn't have a *they*)

- *There were dominoes **that** I swear should have toppled over* (no *they*)

This **is** a relative clause, as can be shown by substituting *which* for *that*, or deleting it altogether

- *There were dominoes **which** I swear should have toppled over*
- *There were dominoes I swear should have toppled over*

That's why you thought the *they* was not required.

But in the sentence provided, *that* is **not** a relative clause marker. **This** *that* is part of the

> [***`X`*** be so **`Adj`** that **`S`**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/53301/the-position-of-strong-enough-in-there-is-no-headache-strong-enough/53311#53311)

Construction, where the **`S`** refers to a tensed clause introduced by a complementizer *that*, like *that he can't think* in

- *He is so exhausted that he can't think.*

This *that* is also deletable, but you can't substitute *which* for it.

- *He is so exhausted he can't think.*
- **He is so exhausted which he can't think.*

So it can't be a relative clause. Furthermore, the `S` introduced by this *that* has to be a full tensed sentence, with a subject noun phrase, and with any object nouns or pronouns present also, since they haven't been deleted or moved by Relative Clause Formation. That's why it really does need the *they*.

There are [several uses for the English word *that*](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/xmasthat.html), and it's easy to confuse the constructions they're in.

Comment: Is it the _so_ _**Adj**_ part of the construction that necessitates a full tensed sentence after the complementizer?  I.e., omitting the _so_ _**Adj**_ allows me to also omit the pronoun?  _There was a man I'd swear was a giant._ vs _There was a man **so tall** I'd swear **he** was a giant._

Comment: It's **much** more complicated than that. A tensed complement clause can't be a tensed relative clause, and vice versa. Relative clauses have to contain a noun phrase that is coreferential with the antecedent noun phrase the relative clause modifies; this coreferential NP is what becomes the relative pronoun and often gets moved from where it would occur. That's what happens to the _they_ in the relative clause example.

Comment: It's the *so Adj* that requires a *That*-complement, but there are lots of other predicates that do, also. A *That*-complement clause **doesn't** modify any noun, at all, may not even mention another noun at all, and **will** require all of its arguments present, until or unless they're extracted by some other rule on a higher cycle, like *Wh*-Question Formation.

Answer (score 7):

The *they* is necessary in your first example:

> There were several dominoes—some so precariously placed that I'd swear **they** should have toppled over.

But in your second example, *they* should not appear:

> There were dominoes that I'd swear should have toppled.

You stripped the first sentence a little too far (*so precariously placed* is part of the "essentials") to get the second.  A truer version would be:

> There were dominoes **so precariously placed** that I'd swear **they** should have toppled.

To explain the rationale behind using or not using *they*: in your first two examples, *that* is part of the **conjunction** *so that*, whereas in your third (stripped) example, *that* is a **pronoun**.  Since in the latter case *that* is the noun, *they* is unnecessary (there is already a noun).  Contrast this with the former case, in which *so ... that* is a conjunction separating two independent clauses (*there were dominoes* and *I'd swear **they** should have toppled*).  The second clause needs to be a complete (independent) sentence, and therefore needs a noun, hence *they*.

Answer (score 2):

Yes (IMHO) the first example should have a *they* but the final one doesn't need one.