# This is too vague a term

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Would anybody indicate me what is the grammatical structure applied in this sentence?

> This is too vague a term

I have seen this structure sometimes and, although they sounded strange in the beginning, I'm starting to naturally use it on my essays.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Sure, there's more than one duplicate of this, but it's a question that no one has ever answered.

Comment: Actually, *this* is fairly specific.  *That* is vague.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just as the construction *vague enough* means ['so vague that **`S`**'](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/53311/15299)

- *The term  was vague enough to describe any book.* ==>
- *The term  was so vague that it described any book.*

the construction *too vague* is its negative, meaning 'so vague that **`Not S`**'

- *The term was too vague to describe the book well.* ==>
- *The term was so vague that it didn't describe the book well.*

If the `S` is not specified, as in the original example, it remains to be interpreted from context by the addressee. Since *vague* is not a clear concept, what this means in practice is 'I don't understand'.

The construction in the original example is somewhat more complex,

- *This is too vague a term.*

instead of

- *This term is too vague.*

Both are grammatical, but if you want the *too `Adj`* construction to be an attributive adjective (i.e, if you want it to modify a noun instead of being a predicate adjective), it must come before a full Noun Phrase, with determiner if any.
So you can't say

- **This is a too vague term.*
- **Maru is in a too small box*

Instead, you have to put *too vague* before the *a*, even though it looks weird.

- *This is too vague a term.* ==>
- *This is so vague a term* (*that* `s.t. bad happens` *or* `s.t. good doesn't happen`)

> (Note that this rule also applies to *so*: i.e, it should be *so vague a term* as well)

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: These are my theories. I'm not a linguist.

```
too small a box to fit
too proud a man to admit his shortcomings
too nice a person
```

The phrases in question are adjective phrases, i.e phrases that are headed by an adjective.

"Too" is an adverb modifying the head adjective. The noun phrases "a box" or "a man" are a mysterious part of the structure of adjective phrases that is not understood. They seem to function as an optional expletive to refer to the thing the adjective is modifying. They aren't necessary, you can always remove them.

In your example, saying "this is too vague", although perfectly grammatical, might be ambiguous if the listener did not know what "this" was. So you can optionally add "a term" to be more explicit.

> This is too vague **a term**.

So, it's like a way to restate what the adjective is modifying.

Comment: Without the noun phrase complement, **too vague** would be too vague an adjective phrase?